# How best to aggregate a list of objective function evaluations in numerical optimization?

Tags: bayesian, optimization

In Bayesian Optimization/other model-based numeric optimization methods, is there a useful way to compress or aggregate the observation history into a single value so you don't have to keep the result of every single function evaluation during a run?

I.e. rather than having a list of exact objective function values which grows ever larger the longer an optimization method runs, you could have some single numeric variable that's recalculated with each new function value seen, and which contains some useful information about the observation history, without the memory requirements of storing the entire thing.

Comment: Great question! Arguably, people who use inducing point methods to fit GPs for BO are doing this, as the inducing points are "unobserved" (X,y) pairs (sometimes y is integrated out) that summarize the actually observed (X,y) and are fewer.